# Python urllib2: How to eliminate urllib2 add it's own headers

Tags: python, urllib2

I am testing some application where I send some POST requests, want to test the behavior of the application when some headers are missing in the request to verify that it generates the correct error codes.

For doing this, my code is as follows.

```
    header = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    data = "hello world"
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data, header)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response = f.read()
```

The problem is urllib2 adds it's own headers like Content-Length, Accept-Encoding when it sends the POST request, but I don't want urllib2 to add any more headers than the one I specified in the headers dict above, is there a way to do that, I tried setting the other headers I don't want to None, but they still go with those empty values as part of the request which I don't want.

Comment: Try reading `urllib2`'s source code and see where the headers are added. To quickly find that, you could use `grep -R Accept-Enconding *`.

Comment: Thanks, I see that the AbstractHTTPHandler extends BaseHandler class and implements these methods, adding some headers if they are not present.

Answer (score 0):

The header takes a dictionary type, example below using a chrome user-agent. For all standard and some non-stranded header fields take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). You also need to encode your data with urllib not urllib2. This is all mention in the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: That still has "Accept-Encoding: identity" in the headers. This doesn't answer the question.